# How do I delete all unused AWS tags from appearing as autocomplete options in console tag fields?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

How do I delete all unused tags in AWS? I know that I can [describe the existing tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html) using the cli with `aws ec2 describe-tags` and that I can [delete a specific tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/delete-tags.html) by name using `aws ec2 delete-tags --tags Key=Stack,Value=Test`, but how do I see and delete tags that are unused by any resources, yet still appearing in autocomplete lists when tagging resources in the console?

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @PeterHowe not yet...